# React Slide Animation removing selected value on unmountOnExit

Tags: reactjs, animation, material-ui, slide

I am facing a issue, on click of radio button the next question comes using slide animation, But on unmounting on Exit the previously selected radio button value is also getting deselected. How to prevent this from happening.

```js
const Quiz = (props) => {
     const {questions, quiz, options} = useSelector((state) => state.quiz);
  
    const [user, setuser] = useState("");
    const [currentQuestion, setCurrentQuestion] = useState(0);
    const [checked, setChecked] = useState(true);  
    const [option, setOptions] = useState("");
    
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const history = useHistory();

 const handleRadioChange = (number, event) => {
  
    let currentSelection = questions.find(question => question.number === number);
    console.log(currentSelection + "radio selected");
    currentSelection.value = event.target.value;
  
    questions[currentQuestion].value = event.target.value;
   
    console.log(questions[currentQuestion].value + "value added");
    setCurrentQuestion((current) => {
      return Math.min(
        current + 1,
        questions.length - 1
      );
    });
      setChecked((previousState) => !previousState);
      setTimeout(() => { 
        setChecked(previousState => ({
             afterPreviousChange: previousState.previousChange 
           }))
      }, 1000);
    
};


    const previousQuestion = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        let new_current_questions = Math.max(currentQuestion - 1, 0);
        setCurrentQuestion(new_current_questions);
        setChecked((previousState) => !!previousState);
       const a =  setTimeout(() => { 
          setChecked(previousState => ({
               afterPreviousChange: previousState.previousChange 
             
             }))
        }, 1000);
       
      };
 function handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();     
        const valid = questions.some((q) => !q.value);
        console.log(valid + "questionsalpha");
        if (!valid) {
            dispatch(postQuiz({ responses: questions, id: quiz.id }, history));
        }
        setChecked((previousState) => !previousState);
        const a =  setTimeout(() => {                
            setChecked((previousState) => !previousState);   
            setCurrentQuestion(0);
              },1000);};
    return(

      <Slide direction="up"  
        in={checked} 
        appear={true} 
        mountOnEnter 
                 unmountOnExit
        timeout={{ enter: 1000 , exit: checked ? 1 : 900}}
    >   
            <Card variant="outlined" sx={{ bgcolor: "#bea"}} elevation={0}>
                <CardContent>
    
                <form onSubmit= {handleSubmit}>
                        <CardActions>
                      <Button type="submit" color="warning" variant="outlined" disabled={currentQuestion===0} className={classes.button} onClick={previousQuestion}>
                          Previous</Button>
                      </CardActions>              
                      <FormControl component='fieldset' className={classes.formControl}
        data-hidden={questions[currentQuestion].number !==
          currentQuestion[questions[currentQuestion].number]} >
        <FormLabel component='legend'>
          {questions[currentQuestion].question}
        </FormLabel>
        <FormLabel component='legend'>
          {questions[currentQuestion].description}
        </FormLabel>
        <RadioGroup
          aria-label='quiz'
          name='quiz'
          defaultValue={' '}
          value={questions[currentQuestion].value}
          checked={checked}
          onChange={(e)=> handleRadioChange(questions[currentQuestion].number, e)}
          sx={{
            color: pink[800],
            '&.Mui-checked': {
              color: blue[600],
            },
          }}>
          {options.map((option) => (
            <FormControlLabel
              key={option.score}
              value={option.score}
              control={<Radio  sx={{
                color: pink[800],
                '&.Mui-checked': {
                  color: blue[600],
                },
              }}/>}
              label={option.label}
             
            />
          ))}
        </RadioGroup>
      </FormControl>
                        <CardActions>
                        <Button type="submit" variant="contained" color="primary" className={classes.button} disabled={currentQuestion<5} onClick={handleSubmit}>
                        Submit
                    </Button>
                  </CardActions>
                    </form>
                    </CardContent>
                    </Card>
                    </Slide>
      );
```

function using handleChange and previous button is also I have shared. Please help with this issue.

Comment: Use a state array to store the option selected at that particular question. If the person reaches on previously visited question, show him the selected option from that state array

Comment: @Aditya: please provide sample code for this. Thanks a lot for taking out time and replying. Please.

Comment: @IgorGonak; please check this also

Comment: @Luis Paulo Pinto : can you please solve the isseue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason for previously radio button value not persist is because you are not changing the `questions` state with the update values, you are just changing the object itself.

The error is specifically here:

```js
let currentSelection = questions.find(question => question.number === number);

console.log(currentSelection + "radio selected");

// HERE YOU ARE CHANGIG ONLY THE OBJECT, NOT THE ARRAY
currentSelection.value = event.target.value;
  
questions[currentQuestion].value = event.target.value;
```

One way to do this is map the questions array, change the current question value and then update the questions state:

```js
const updatedQuestions = questions.map((item) => {
   if (item.number === currentQuestion) item.value = event.target.value;
      return item;
   });

setQuestions(updatedQuestions);
```

But your code also have other inconsistencies, i did a [code sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-questions-slide-animation-yp5p8b?file=/src/Example.jsx) for you with comments.

Comment: thanks a lot for such a detail answer, I was looking for this answer pointing the inconsistencies. One thing I want to ask, I have user Redux, will that affect the code who have shared,   @Luis Paulo Pinto:

Comment: The answer is yes, you can implement this with Redux. As i used some mock data, you just need to do some changes and adapt the redux code with the proper data..

Comment: using useSelector how the options will be updated?

Comment: `const updatedQuestions = questions.map((item) => {
   if (item.number === currentQuestion) item.value = event.target.value;
      return item;
   });

setQuestions(updatedQuestions)`     how to do this with useSelector that i hve used? can u please elaborate? @Luis Paulo Pinto: thnks

Comment: I am not familiar with redux, so i really couldn't tell you. What i can tell is that it can be implemented with whatever state control that you want.

Comment: Thanks will try now.

Comment: Hey i made changes according to my requirement but its not working.

Comment: Sorry to hear that, like a said, i'm not familiar with redux. But if you are using it would be good to you include this part of code on your question too. So anyone who see your question could try to simulate it using the redux.

Comment: Thanks and the code which you provide was helpful in other way to me . Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: Hey can you once just check I have added some lines of code, that can be helpful in making changes in the code which you provided. @Luis Paulo Pinto: Thanks

Comment: can you please help me out with the working of submit button. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72469543/submit-button-should-appear-after-every-5-questions-react    @Luis Paulo Pinto