# On React Router, stay on the same page even if refreshed

Tags: reactjs, authentication, mern

my site is built using MERN stack, when I refresh a page it first shows the main page and then the page where the user is. How to fix this issue?
For example:

if I refresh (/profile) page then for a meanwhile it shows  (/) then it redirects to (/profile). I want if I refresh (/profile) it should be on the same page.

```
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, authed, ...rest }) => {
   
    return (
        <Route
            {...rest}
            render={(props) => authed === true
                ? <Component {...props} />
                : <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/', state: { from: props.location } }} />}
        />
    )
}

export default PrivateRoute;
```

Router code:

```
const App = () => {
  const user = useSelector((state) => state?.auth);

  return (
    <>
    
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Container maxWidth="lg">
        
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
          
          <Route path="/about" exact component={About} />
          <Route path="/terms" exact component={Terms} />
        
          <PrivateRoute authed={user?.authenticated} path='/profile' component={Profile} />
         
        </Switch>
      
      </Container>
     
    </BrowserRouter>
   
   
 </>
  )
}

export default App;
```

How to fix so that user stays on the same page if its refreshed? The issue is on the pages where authentication is required.

Comment: I don't quit get what you need. Can you make an example? So you have a route to the page like /test and when you refresh you are on home again?

Comment: @IgorGonak: If I refresh /test page it for a meanwhile shows / page then redirects to /test page. How to be on /test page after refresh

Comment: that's really strange. how is your router looks like? Could you possibly provide a minimal working example in codesandbox or something?

Comment: @IgorGonak: I have added the router code above please check

Comment: does it happen only on your private route "/profile"?

Comment: Yes @IgorGonak: It happens with private route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When first authenticated the user, store the credentials(the info that you evaluate to see if the user is authenticated. Tokens etc.) in the `localStorage`. Of course you have to create necessary states too.
Then with `useEffect` hook on every render set the credential state from `localStorage`.

```
function YourComponentOrContext(){
  const[credentials, setCredentials] = useState(null);
  
  function yourLoginFunction(){
    // Get credentials from backend response as response
    setCredentials(response);
    localStorage.setItem("credentials", response);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    let storedCredentials = localStorage.getItem("credentials");
    if(!storedCredentials) return;
    setCredentials(storedCredentials);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess on mounting (=first render) your *user* variable is empty. Then something asynchronous happen and you receive a new value for it, which leads to new evaluation of `{user?.authenticated}` resulting in true and causing a redirect to your */profile* page.

I must say I'm not familiar with Redux (I see useSelector in your code, so I assume you are using a Redux store), but if you want to avoid such behaviour you need to retrieve the right *user* value on mounting OR only render route components when you've got it later.

Comment: This means I have to use localstorage to store user token then I can retreive the correct value

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72385191/slide-up-and-down-not-working-on-card-using-react-transition-group Please check this also

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72273800/react-slide-animation-removing-selected-value-on-unmountonexit 
Please check this also @IgorGonak: